# How can I scope HTML page actions to a unique UserId in JS/Coffee file?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

My app displays todo lists for multiple people on a single html page with each having their own inline-block.

There can be multiple users (varies), but each person has a single unique list of todos.  This list can show all of their todos, or a subset (ie. personal, work, etc).

In the app, each person is a single Mongo document with an array of todos (embedded vs referenced for performance).  Here is the basic model:

```
People.insert({
    name: "Joe",
        todos: 
        [{
        id: Random.id(),
        description: "Pick up Flowers",
        list: "Home"
        },
        {
        id: Random.id(),
        description: "Complete this task.",
        list: "Work"
        }})
```

The collection of users is passed to an {{#each}} helper where the users {{name}} and their list of todos all have their own inline-block.  The todos for each as presented using:

```
{{#each person}}
    {{name}}
    {{#each this.todos}}
        {{description}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

There is a drop down menu for each user where they can switch between lists (ie. work or home).  See code:

```
<select id="{{_id}}-Toggle" class="toggleList">
    <option value = "1">Home</option>
    <option value = "2">Work</option>
</select>
```

**The issue is as follows:**

When an action is taken on a user's list (ex. mark a task complete, add a new task, delete a task, switch between lists, etc), I can't seem to scope it to that particular user. (I tried making the DOM Id's unique using the Person_id, but then I can't call them using click events in my coffee file since the dom element ID becomes dynamic and my coffee file can't know it beforehand in the Template.event.

I also tried including the People_id in a hidden field, but I can't seem to pass it to my coffeescript file uniquely since the class of "id" will be replicated for each user.  See code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{_id}}" value="{{_id}}" class="id"/>
```

Here is how the coffee file event for the drop down menu is set-up:

```
Template.people.events
        'change .toggleList': () ->
            choice = $('.toggleList option:selected').text()
            console.log "You selected #{choice}."

            user = $('.id').val()
            console.log "user is #{user}."
```

In the first case, I see both selected items in the two dropdowns (2 users in the People Collection).  This is since I am selecting a class and it picks up both.  The user always grabs the same user (again, likely as I am selecting a class.)

Comment: can you show your coffee file? how you're actually trying to manipulate the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to "this" in event handlers (see http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps), so you don't need to put {{_id}}s in your templates. If your select.toggleList is rendered within your {{#each person}} block, you can refer to this._id in the handler (although I'd recommend starting the handler with a defensive "self = this" and using self._id).

Comment: That's awesome Donny.  Super simple.  I'll have to dive into event maps and this a bit more.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

i think as far as i understand the problem, you can grab the user's ID right of the select box when the `change` event is triggered

```
'change .toggleList': (event)->
  select_box = $(event.target)
  console.log "You selected: #{select_box.val()}"

  console.log "And the user's ID is: #{select_box.attr('id').split('-')[0]}"
```